# How to send group mail in Outlook to multiple recipients, but have each recipient see their own name?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, recipient

I would like to know how to send an e-mail in Outlook 2003 to a group of recipients in which each recipient will see only himself in "TO" field. You can see an example below;

[image: Click to enlarge]

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for the add-in called [Send Personally](http://www.mapilab.com/outlook/send_personally/):

> Send Personally is the add-in for Microsoft® Outlook® designed to send
>   individual emails to a great number of recipients via Microsoft
>   Outlook 2010 / 2007 / 2003 / XP / 2000. This add-in for Outlook offers
>   you an alternative method of sending personalized emails from Outlook:
>   separate messages are being created for each recipient. The final
>   recipient will receive no information about any of the other
>   recipients. Moreover, he/she will see only his/her name and address in
>   the "To" field, as if the message is sent to him/her only.

**Note:** You can also achieve the same result by using the [Mail Merge](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2008/09/22/mail-merge-how-to-send-a-personalized-e-mail-to-many-people-at-once.aspx) feature in Outlook. This method does exactly what the Outlook add-in does and its **FREE**.

Answer (score 2):

Simply putting all the recipients in the `Bcc:` field should do it, although that way they won't see their name in the `To:` field. [More information on Bcc at the Microsoft Office website.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/use-bcc-effectively-HA001200237.aspx)

Alternatively, you could use a mail merge. Again, [more information can be found at the Microsoft Office website](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/redir/HA001146481.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA001200237).

Comment: I know bcc method but when you use bcc,  "To" field seems empty.I would like to get only one name in To field of each recipient.

Comment: @NT: See second paragraph; as far as I know, that is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a **free** [Send Messages Personally](http://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesSendPersonally/) add-in from Outlook Freeware (starting with 'S') and a commercial product, [ReliefJet Essentials for Outlook](http://www.reliefjet.com/Product/Features#Productivity), (I'm one of its developers and its name starts with 'R').

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Mail-merge plug in for which let you send a text to multiple recipient having their name and other filed customized to each on. You need to write the letter in WORD and use Mailmerg tab to send them at the same time by a single click. 
You can also use "MailMerge-toolkit" which let you have moer option in sending.